# How to hide angular bootstrap popover on blur?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Angular bootstrap popover (tooltip) has possible events to open hide popover.
{
'mouseEnter': 'mouseLeave',
'click': 'click',
'focus': 'blur'
}

What i need is show on 'focus' hide on 'blur'. But i deal with DIV element not an INPUT, so i can't use focus/blur (it just doesn't work)

How can i override tooltip/popover modules to emulate blur event (by handling click on body etc.)?

Comment: So you want the popover to show when the user clicks on a div? What would have to occur for 'blur' to be triggered?

Comment: I want to show tooltip after click, and hide it after another click but anywhere on the page, not exactly on that small tooltip icon i have. Everywhere except tooltip itself.

Answer (score 0):

i know this topic is old, but maybe someone still need help,

i used popover as a directive, and i used below property on directive declaration  :

```
template: '<a href uib-popover-template="\'app/modules/directives/quickView/quickView.template.html\'" popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="outsideClick" ng-transclude></a>',
```

So, i think you need to use :

```
popover-trigger="outsideClick"
```

i hope my reply is helpful .